# Should I define async function if I explicitly return a Promise?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

We know that `async` functions return a Promise implicitly. But I have a purely pedantic question. Should I put an `async` keyword if I return a Promise explicitly?

Is this:

```js
const wait = async ms => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
);
```

Any different than this?

```js
const wait = ms => new Promise(
    resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)
);
```

I believe that technically they are identical. Is there any style guide or official recommendation behind any of these two ways to define this kind of function?

Comment: I wouldn't, you're not `await`ing inside, so it's just syntax noise IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance part of me agrees with your point, I feel like `async` keyword in JavaScript is a little confusing. I don't like it how it's required only to use with `await`. Is it like that in other languages too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are four main reasons I think about for using `async` functions:

1. You want to use `await`.
2. You want it to automatically catch synchronous exceptions and turn them into a rejected promise.
3. You want it to always return a promise, regardless of what your function actually returns.
4. You like the fact that making the function `async` makes it clear to callers looking at the code that the function always returns a promise - essentially self documenting.

So, if you aren't using `await` and you don't need point #2 and you are manually returning a promise already, then there's really no requirement to declaring the function as `async`.

---

A few more thoughts on the points above.

Point #1 requires `async` if you're going to use `await`.  There is no other way around it.

Points #2 and #3 are really just programming conveniences.  If you either catch your own synchronous exceptions or are sure there are no synchronous exceptions and you are controlling all code paths to return a promise, then `async` is not necessary.

Both points #2 and #3 can arise if your code has both a synchronous code path and an asynchronous code path, such as checking a cache and returning a value if its present in the cache and, if not in the cache, then make a network request to fetch the value.  As described above, this can be coded manually without `async`, but the code can sometimes be a little simpler with `async` because it will automaticlly catch your synchronous exceptions and automatically wrap a return value in a promise.

Point #4 is just a coding style preference.  If you like the "self-documenting" aspects of making the function `async`, you can do that as an indication that it always returns a promise.

---

And, for anyone interested in lots of technical detail about how `async` functions work internlly and have been optimized over the years, this is a fairly indepth article on the topic: [V8 blog on fast async](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async).

Comment: How about adding `async` just for the sake of readability as "it makes sense to `await` for this function"?

Comment: @RoboRobok - I suppose.  Certainly that tells the caller that it will always return a promise, but generally you need some doc somewhere that tells you what the function returns anyway so I personally wouldn't do it only for that reason.  But, that's certainly just a personal preference thing.

Comment: @RoboRobok - I decided to add point #4 about the self-documenting aspect of making it `async`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Also please take a look at 3limin4t0r's answer below, especially at the bottom. Not sure about you, but I wasn't aware of that difference.

Comment: @RoboRobok - I've never had an issue where I'm comparing to a specific promise reference such that the `async` wrapping would be an issue.  I don't even know how an outside caller would have a promise reference that the function was returning unless it was somehow passed into the function as an argument.  Anyway, that is technically a difference, it just doesn't seem like something that would come up often or perhaps ever.

Comment: Well, in some complex scenarios you'd want a Promise to be passed around. Also I'm a bit surprised that `async` actually wraps a Promise in another Promise.

Comment: @RoboRobok - I guess I've never seen a situation where you're passing in a promise and requiring it to return the same promise (so chaining onto that promise and returning the new promise is not allowed).  But, certainly if that was the case, `async` should not be used.

Comment: @RoboRobok - If you want to see some of the internals of how an `async` function works with `await`, this is a very interesting [article](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-async#fn2).  It does not directly address why an `async` function always rewraps a returned promise in a new promise, but I think it shows in the description of how an `async` function internally always starts with `createPromise()`.  Anyway, it's interesting reading for other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

In the given example the `async` keyword is essentially only wrapping the return value in `Promise.resolve()`. See the [async function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description).

So on one hand you have:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

While on the other you have:

```
const wait = async ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
// is similar to
const wait = ms => Promise.resolve(new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms)));
```

They are essentially the same and I would personally go for the variant without the `async` keyword.

> **Note:**
>
> Even though the return value of an async function behaves as if it's
> wrapped in a `Promise.resolve`, they are not equivalent.
>
> An async function will return a different *reference*, whereas
> `Promise.resolve` returns the same reference if the given value is a
> promise.
>
> It can be a problem when you want to check the equality of a promise
> and a return value of an async function.
>
> ```
> const p = new Promise((res, rej) => {
>   res(1);
> })
>
> async function asyncReturn() {
>   return p;
> }
>
> function basicReturn() {
>   return Promise.resolve(p);
> }
>
> console.log(p === basicReturn()); // true
> console.log(p === asyncReturn()); // false
> ```

Comment: Oh! Interesting find with the equality check in the documentation, great to know that.